# Can someone help me understand foreign key relationships?

Tags: database-design

I have four entities, a Company, QuestionList, a Question, and an Answer

A Company has a QuestionList.
A QuestionList has one or more Questions.
A Question has an Answer.

My four Entities are Company, QuestionList, Question, Answer

Company has the primary key company_id.
QuestionList has the primary key questionList_id.
Now do I reference company_id as a foreign key in QuestionList or do i reference questionList_id in Company as a foreign key?

Comment: Sorry I'm not at the level of implementing yet, I'm learning how to design the models in ERD form which I'm just doing conceptually. Should i try to be doing this in code?

Answer (score 0):

Neither. You create table that relates both called Company_QuestionList_Relation that contains only two columns that are the primary keys of the two tables. :)

Comment: So I would also need to create a link table between QuestionList and Question and Question and Answer right? I would need QuestionList_Question and Question_Answer

Comment: Not really Answer usually cannot exist without a Question so in that case it may be natural to keep that relation in the Answer table. the Question to question list absolutely.

Comment: Can the same question list be shared by more than one company?

Comment: the companies cannot share the question list. The answer by mertyildiran is confusing me more, that is without normalization right?

Comment: In a lot of cases its 6 vs half a dozen. The way I like to keep things for example is if something cannot exist without the other (like an answer without a question) then adding the foreign key in Answer is ok. However if Company and Question or QuestionList are separate entities that makes sense individually then I keep the relation in a spate table to makes sure I am not locked in one way of viewing things.

Comment: @driftdrift Sorry I did not notice your response earlier. Then you do not need a QuestionList table at all :) Just have a Company_Question_Relation Table, your list comes from querying that table for all question where company_id is the company you are interested in. The quesion list id is the company_id since they are one to one. The QuestionList is an abstraction that holds no added information, and so does not need to exist as a separate table in the database. Does that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> In the context of relational databases, a foreign key is a field (or
>   collection of fields) in one table that uniquely identifies a row of
>   another table. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Foreign Key is such a concept that if you store *another table*'s Primary Key to **uniquely identify a row** from this *another table* in your table, we call this field as Foreign Key.

This Entity-Relation Diagram that I quickly drew for you is briefly explains the solution of your problem:

[image]

If you want to store multiple foreign keys in a field (I mean create a relation with an element/row of a table with more than one rows of another table), you need to store foreign keys as an array like 00001, 00002, 00003, ... Then you need to parse and convert this field to an actual array type in your program because obviously array definitions are differs from language to language.

Comment: this would be the answer without considering normalization?

Comment: @driftdrift What part needs normalization I couldn't see at the first glance?

Comment: This says each company has at zero or one questionList, each questionList has zero or one question, each question has zero or one answer, and is not normalized at that.

Comment: @DourHighArch As long as foreign keys are nullable, what is the problem with that zero or one issue?

Comment: The OP said “A QuestionList has one or more Questions” and that's not what you gave him. “Has an” usually means “at least one”, not zero or one. Your design also allows lists without companies, questions without lists, and answers without questions.

Comment: @DourHighArch Then they will be not nullable. OP is asking for an explanation for foreign key relationships. I closed my diagram tool and I can not redraw the diagram and update this part of my answer. I have explained “A QuestionList has one or more Questions” part with an addition to my answer before your last comment.

Comment: @DourHighArch I spend effort to draw the diagram. Obviously it's not the best diagram of the world but I'm sure it is an explanation for a question about "Understaing for foreign key relationships". If you have time and energy to draw a better diagram, just draw it. It's not clear what do you oppose about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To represent the association between Company and QuestionList, you need two columns in the same table: `company_id, questionlist_id`. Which table and how to constrain those columns depends on the cardinality and optionality of the relationship.

If a Company has just one QuestionList, that means QuestionList depends on company, or in other words, Company determines QuestionList. For this we want a table in which `company_id` is a key - either a separate table or we could include `questionlist_id` in the Company table.

If a QuestionList has just one Company, then Company depends on QuestionList and QuestionList determines company, for which we want a table with `questionlist_id` as a key - either a separate table or we could include `company_id` in the QuestionList table.

The dependency may hold both ways - each Company has one exclusive QuestionList. We can follow any approach above, provided that we make the non-primary column unique.

If Companies can have multiple QuestionLists, and QuestionLists can belong to multiple Companies, then a separate table is the only option. In this case the combination of `company_id, questionlist_id` will be a key.

You can apply this reasoning to any binary relationship.

Note that I didn't mention anything about foreign key constraints. They're integrity constraints and don't have anything to do with implementing relationships. Relationships map to sets of columns in tables; most ERD software and online tutorials get it wrong.